# How can I ensure the relevant command is run based on arguments passed in BASH?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm writing my first bash script that will do some visual testing using wraith. I've stripped down the code to make it easier to read.

What I'm trying to write:
- The BASH command accepts an argument - 1, 2 or 3. i.e. `regressiontest 1`
- `server` will be assigned the argument passed
- `alias config` will be assigned to `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-1.yaml`, `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-2.yaml` or 
`wraith capture configs/capture-staging-3.yaml`
- The echo statement is written to a txt file.

The script works as expected. The only issue is:
If run `regressiontest 1`, all good, runs `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-1.yaml` as expected.

I run `regressiontest 2`, I would expect it to run `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-2.yaml` but seems to run `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-1.yaml` again.

It seems to be running using the previous config file. If I close and open terminal again, it works as expected but if I run the same command with a different argument consecutively it seems to always run the first command I use.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm new to BASH scripts and am having trouble googling to find an answer

```
function regressiontest {

    regressionfolder=~/path/to/folder

    cd $regressionfolder

    alias config

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No arguments provided - USAGE: regressiontest <server>"
        return 0
    else
        server=$1
    fi

    if [ $server != 1 ] && [ $server != 2 ] && [ $server != 3 ]; then
        echo "Visual Regression Testing argument invalid - USAGE: regressiontest <server>"
    return 0
    elif [ $server == 1 ]; then
        server="1"
        alias config='wraith capture configs/capture-staging-1.yaml'
    elif [ $server == 2 ]; then
        server="2"
        alias config='wraith capture configs/capture-staging-2.yaml'
    elif [ $server == 3 ]; then
        server="3"
        alias config='wraith capture configs/capture-staging-3.yaml'
    fi

    echo "https://website-staging-$server/" > data/server.txt

    config
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks, All
Moe

Comment: I believe you should compare integers using `-eq`, try to rewrite the script with `-eq` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking right, but making things harder than need be. Your initial part of the script is fine, though I would validate that the `cd` succeeds, e.g.

```
    regressionfolder=~/path/to/folder

    cd "$regressionfolder" || {
        printf "error: unable to change to %s\n" "$regressionfolder" >&2
        return 1
    }
```

(**note:** a return of `1` generally indicates error and always *double-quote* your variables)

After your check on `"$server" != 1 ...` all you need to do is set your alias with `$server` as the number. No additional `if ... elif ...` are required, e.g.

```
    if [ "$server" != 1 ] && [ "$server" != 2 ] && [ "$server" != 3 ]; then
        echo "Visual Regression Testing argument invalid - USAGE: regressiontest <server>"
        return 1
    fi

    alias config="wraith capture configs/capture-staging-$server.yaml"

    config
}
```

(**note:** always *double-quote* variables withing `[...]`)

**Eliminate the `alias`**

There is no need for the `alias`, you can simply run:

```
wraith capture configs/capture-staging-$server.yaml
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
function regressiontest {

    regressionfolder="$HOME/path/to/folder"

    cd "$regressionfolder" || {
        printf "error: unable to change to %s\n" "$regressionfolder" >&2
        return 1
    }

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No arguments provided - USAGE: regressiontest <server>"
        return 1
    else
        server=$1
    fi

    if [ "$server" != 1 ] && [ "$server" != 2 ] && [ "$server" != 3 ]; then
        printf "Visual Regression Testing argument invalid - "
        printf "USAGE: regressiontest <server>\n"
        return 1
    fi

    wraith capture "configs/capture-staging-$server.yaml"
}
```

(**note:** also the use of `"$HOME"` instead of `~`. While `~` will expand on the command line, you will quickly run into problems using it within scripts)

**Use a `case` Statement**

A shorter more condensed version of your function using `case ... esac` would probably be a bit better, e.g.

```
function regressiontest {

    regressionfolder="$HOME/path/to/folder"

    cd "$regressionfolder" || {
        printf "error: unable to change to %s\n" "$regressionfolder" >&2
        return 1
    }

    case "$server" in
        [123]   )   wraith capture "configs/capture-staging-$server.yaml";;
            *   )   printf "Visual Regression Testing argument invalid - "
                    printf "USAGE: regressiontest <server>\n"
                    return 1;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Marked as answer for `wraith capture configs/capture-staging-$server.yaml`
sorted my issue completely. Thank you :D

Comment: Good, glad to help. Bash is a wonderful and very capable shell. There is a lot to learn, don't rush it, enjoy the learning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to declare aliases, but store commands for later execution; just remove the "alias" from `alias config='…'` and at the end call it via `$config`.